# Inserting Errors into an InlineFormSet Custom Validator

Tags: django, error-handling, django-forms, inline-formset

I am using the following custom form validator to ensure that there is not more than one `correct` entry submitted to my application through an InlineFormSet.

```
class BaseAnswerFormSet(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors):
            return
        if len([d['correct'] for d in self.forms if d['correct'].value()]) !=1:
            raise forms.ValidationError("There must be one and only one correct answer")
        return
```

This is working, as the form object that is presented will return `False` when evaluated as `.is_clean()` but there is no error returned. Here is what it shows up as when I use `pdb` in the view that handles the `POST`:

```
(Pdb) answerformset.is_valid()
False
(Pdb) answerformset.errors
[{}, {}, {}]
```

Shouldn't the `raise forms.ValidationError("There must be one...` create an error entry? I know that each of the empty dicts in the `answerformset.errors` list is for each of the answer forms, but I thought that there would be a `non_field_error` or something like that?

How can I get this clean function to return an error that I can display in a template? How can I add a non_field_error to this?

Comment: Instead of simply using `return` use `return self.cleaned_data` see if that change throw error?

Comment: Hey Aamir, that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: ok do `print answerformset.non_field_errors` did it print error?

Comment: Yes, it is there now! Let me check it out more in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [Custom Formset Validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation). `Formset` custom errors can be accessed using `non_form_errors`:

```
answerformset.non_form_errors()
```